# How do I resolve template tag errors?

Tags: expressionengine, web-development-server, templatetags

I'm very new to web development, so I'll try to include as much as possible, and I'm happy to answer any follow up questions.

I'm trying to update ExpressionEngine on a website from version 2 to version 6, but I am getting "template tag errors" with two different addons.

I've tried:

- Uninstalling them from the admin page prior to the update
- Not including their files at all during the update process
- Removing anything related to them from the database

and various combinations of those.

Somehow I'm still getting a template tag error referring to those addons, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Some addons from the EE2 era don't uninstall properly on EE6 (or even EE2) so i'd recommend uninstalling those addons before upgrading. Probably best to uninstall via the addon manager first, then check to see wether all traces of them are gone in the DB.
However there might also be places where those addons (especially field types) are a bit hidden from sight: they might be used in a matrix or grid field, so worth checking those first
addons in the DB are normally found in: exp_modules, exp_plugins, exp_fieldtypes or exp_extentions so be sure to check those tables
then in the templates you should remove all mentions of those tags. Sometimes i've seen that only hiding them in comments like {!-- {exp:my_plugin} --} isn't sufficient, so properly delete them. Which addons are bothering you?
Also, there's more EE devs over on https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/ and the Slack channel where we would be happy to help